# Time inside docker is completely random

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

I have a **Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+** with a **Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch)** and I am trying to build a docker container with a Dockerfile. For some reason, the date is always different inside the container. Right now it's somewhere around 2037, but I've also seen it at 1. Jan 1970.

The Dockerfile for showing this issue can be as simple as:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN date
```

The issue also exists when using Debian as a base image. This issue prevents me from installing packages due to invalid certificates.
When running **date** outside the container, I get the right time. This is not the first time building a container on the Pi, but so far it always worked.

Edit:

I got closer to fixing the problem by using a different alpine version. It works now with 3.12.7. 3.13.5 resulted in "Sun Jan  0 00:100:4174038  1900". Not really sure what the issue is.

Comment: But doesn't Docker simply use the time from the host?

Comment: The Raspberries don't have a realtime hardware clock, try installing the package `fake-hwclock` on the host. Docker might not be able to pull the date without that.

Comment: This package is already installed and at the newest version

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it an optimal solution, but one way to mitigate this is to manually set the timezone.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV TZ=America/New_York
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

Comment: Does not work, with debian:stable-slim I get 1969 and with alpine:latest I get 2037